# Como saber de onde veio a rota e redirecionar de volta?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, view, controller, route

Tenho 3 tabelas no **BD**: `Emitentes, Pessoas e Cidades`. Sendo que na tabela **Emitentes** e na tabela **Pessoas** tenho a `FK` `id_cidade`. 
Quando estou cadastrando um, tanto um `Emitente` quanto uma `Pessoa` tenho nas views um link que me redireciona pra página de `Cidades`:

**Emitentes/Pessoas:**

```
{!! Form::label('id_cidade', 'Cidade:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
{!! Form::text('id_cidade', $id_cidade, ['class' => 'form-control',  'readonly']) !!}
{!! Form::label('uf', 'UF:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
{!! Form::text('uf', $nomeestado, ['class' => 'form-control', 'readonly']) !!}
<a href="{{ route('cidades.index') }}" class="btn btn-info" onClick="save()"> Selecionar&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
```

E na página `cidades.index` tenho um link que me redireciona para a página de **Emitentes**:

```
<tbody>@foreach($cidades as $cidade)<tr>
<td>
<a href="{{ URL::to('cidades/' . $cidade->id . '/selecionacidade') }}" class="btn btn-success">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
</td>
<td>{{ e($cidade->cidade) }}</td>
<td>{{ e($cidade->estado) }}</td>
```

**Rota:**

```
Route::get('cidades/{id}/selecionacidade','CidadesController@selecionacidade');
```

**Controller Cidades:**

```
public function selecionacidade($id, Request $request){
  $request->session()->put('selecionacidade', 1);  
  $cidade = Cidade::findOrFail($id);  
  $request->session()->put('codigocidade', $id);  

  $request->session()->put('nomecidade', $cidade->cidade);
  $request->session()->put('nomeestado', $cidade->estado);
  $caminhocidade = $request->session()->get('caminhocidade'); //url de edição ou inserção
  $emitenteid = $request->session()->get('emitenteid');  
      return redirect()->route($caminhocidade, $emitenteid); }
```

Tudo funciona perfeitamente para cadastrar **Emitentes**, mas eu tentei fazer o mesmo para a view de **Pessoas**, fiz um nova função no `CidadesController` para selecionar a cidade para cadastrar **Pessoas**, fiz uma nova rota, e ela continuava me redirecionando para a `view` de cadastro de **Emitentes**. Então fiquei me perguntando se teria como saber de que `view` eu fui direcionada, e se teria como ser direcionada de volta para aquela `view` com o valor `id_cidade` armazenado. Assim funcionando para os dois ***cadastros***.

*Peço desculpas pela pergunta extensa, mas não vi outra maneira de especificar o que precisava.*

Comment: Olhando assim `Route::get('cidades/{id}/selecionacidade','CidadesController@selecionacidade');` não seria melhor colocar um parâmetro a mais para definir aonde ele vai voltar? tipo `Route::get('cidades/{id}/selecionacidade/{volta}','CidadesController@selecionacidade');` ????????

Comment: Sim, você tem toda razão. Era seu comentário mesmo que eu estava aguardando. Muito obrigada!

Comment: Uma sugestão: vejo muitos sites utilizando a url de retorno na própria url. Você poderia utilizar um parâmetro `get` para fazer isso. Dependendo do contexto, eu também não utilizaria sessão para salvar os dados, e sim u registro no banco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o objetivo é saber *de onde veio a rota*, você poderia capturar globalmente ou num método específico do controller qual é a url atual e enviá-la para  sessão.

```
session(['url.previous' => $request->url()]);

return redirect('/novo_redirecionamento');
```

Na outra página você teria o valor da url anterior salvo em `session('url.previous')`.

Também é possível usar os headers para isso:

```
$request->headers->get('referer')
```